# Wordpress creating post for each images

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress and it is creating lots of posts for each images , For example below is image

```
https://websitica.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/13071717_232064583833046_1659267533112004235_o-300x225.jpg
```

and below is post created for it

```
https://websitica.com/13071717_232064583833046_1659267533112004235_o/
```

.Its not available in posts or pages.

Edit : I tried Redirect post to parent , but following url dont have parent

Comment: this is a statement of what you observed that wp does, not a question ...

Comment: These are called "attachment pages" and can be disabled with various plugins including Yoast SEO plugin.